# How to set up a VPN server (L2TP/IPsec) and connect it to an other VPN server?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, vps, ipsec, l2tp

I have configured an L2TP/IPsec vpn server on Ubuntu, and i want to connect this vpn server to an other one. Because I live in Iran and the internet is heavily  censored by the goverment. some times they approximately  shut down the internet and just run a intranet. I have found  some servers which is always connected to Internet and will never down, But even the traffic of them is passed through Iran Filtering System. So I have transformed one of those to a Virtual Private Server(L2TP/IPsec) and now  I want to connect it to an other vpn in order to by pass the Filtering.

Comment: Here is my config: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/L2TPServer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very roundabout way to counter censorship. Why not use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) instead. You may download [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) bundle here and use bridges so as to avoid any suspicion.

Now, coming to actual question. You may  download [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) bundle and then configure it to use your VPN server. I am not sure which Client OS you're using but this is official link for windows - [https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-server-with-the-desktop-client/ below](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-server-with-the-desktop-client/)

Comment: Because also The Tor Browser  is filtered! (LoL). Thanks for your response, But the problem is: connecting two vpn server(nested vpn), not connecting a vpn server and client. I just can communicate with server by ssh.

Comment: @CyrusKlantarpour 1. So you want to first connect your computer to "VPN Server A"(configured by you and it's inside Iran's firewall) and then connect this VPN Server A to VPN Server B(which is outside Iran's firewall) ? 2. What do you mean by Tor Browser is flitered? Tor Website is filtered? If yes, then you can download it from here : https://github.com/TheTorProject/gettorbrowser/releases

Comment: If you cannot make connections via Tor, because tor traffic is being censored, then it can be by-passed via OBSF4 bridges. You can get them here : https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4